# Query parameter updating too early

Tags: reactjs

So I have a selectbox and when I click on one of the options I want the value to be added to the query. Problem is that it keeps adding the previous value instead of the one I just clicked.

Example:

```
<option value="1">First option</option>
<option value="2">Second option</option>
<option value="3">Third option</option>
```

Clicking First option gives me 'url?value='

Clicking Second option gives me 'url?value=1'

Clicking Third option gives me 'url?value=2'

Clicking Second option gives me 'url?value=3'

Relevant code:

```
  const [fetched_data, set_fetched_data] = useState({
    category_result: [],
    subcategory_result: [],
    is_loading: true,
  });

  //the necessary value is saved inside 'category_id'
  const [selected_data, set_selected_data] = useState({
     category_id: '',
     is_set: false
  })

  
  const get_subcategory = () => {
    //add query parameter
    const url = new URL(window.location);
    url.searchParams.set('c', selected_data.category_id);
    window.history.pushState({}, '', url);

    Axios.get('/getSelectedSubcategories').then((response) => {
      const subcategory_list = response.data.result;

      set_fetched_data({
        is_loading: false,
        category_result: fetched_data.category_result,
        subcategory_result: subcategory_list.map(subcategory => <option key={subcategory.id} value={subcategory.id}>{ subcategory.subcategory_name }</option>),
      })
    })
  }


  return (
    <div>
    //saves the selected value into state and then runs function to update the query parameter
    <select name="categories" onChange={ async (e) => { await set_selected_data({category_id: e.target.value, is_set: true}); await get_subcategory(); }}>
      <option defaultValue>-</option>
      { !fetched_data.is_loading && fetched_data.category_result }
    </select> 
    </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated query parameters inside useEffect() an launched my function after option is selected for the first time.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = new URL(window.location);
    url.searchParams.set('c', selected_data.category_id);
    window.history.pushState({}, '', url);

    if(selected_data.is_set){
      get_subcategory();
    }
  }, [selected_data.category_id])
```